# Understanding von Dyck's theorem

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

I'm trying to understand how to use Von Dyck's theorem to prove that $S_3 \cong D_3$. I believe I have a correct sketch, but I'm very fuzzy on the details, mainly because I haven't seen free groups yet and therefore don't have a full understanding of the statement of the theorem.

My rough understanding is that if I have two group presentations for groups $G$ and $H$ and the defining relations of $G$ hold in $H$, then there exists a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $H$. So let's take $G = D_3$ and $H = S_3$. I define
\begin{align*}
S_3 & = \left \langle x, y \mid x^2 = e = y^3 \right \rangle = \left\{\mathrm{id}, (12),(13), (23), (123), (132) \right\} \\
D_3 & = \left \langle r,s \mid r^3 = 1, \; s^2 = 1, \; sr = r^{-1} s \right \rangle = \left\{e, r, r^2, s, rs, r^2 s \right\}.
\end{align*}
To do this check, do I need to "identify" the generators of one group with another? For example, it only makes sense that I identify the generators of order $2$, $x = (12)$ and $s$, and the generators of order $3$, $(123)$ and $r$. After that, I do the direct calculation. Let $\tau = (12)$ and $\sigma = (123)$. We compute:
\begin{align*}
\sigma^3 = \tau^2 = \mathrm{id} \text{ and } \tau \sigma = (23) = \sigma^{-1} \tau. 
\end{align*}
Therefore, the defining relations of $D_3$ are true in $S_3$, so by von Dyck's theorem, there exists a surjective hommorphism $D_3 \twoheadrightarrow S_3$. As $|D_3| = 6 = |S_3|$, this surjective map must also be injective, and we have $D_3 \cong S_3$.

Is this the correct way to apply the theorem? Do I need to "align the generators," as I've done, or does the labelling not matter? Another way to view it is that, despite what I call the generators, I know that $S_3$ is generated by $\sigma$ and $\tau$ and I know that I can define a group by the relations I just checked, so despite what I call the elements, I've identified $S_3$ with another group. The map would ultimately map generators to generators and the "corresponding" elements to each other.

Comment: The presentation you give for $S_3$ is not $S_3$; the presentation $\langle x,y\mid x^2=e=y^3\rangle$ defines the infinite group $C_2*C_3$ (free product of the cyclic group of order $2$ and the cyclic group of order $3$). You are missing relations between $x$ and $y$ to present $S_3$; for example, a presentation is given by $$\langle x,y\mid x^2=y^3=e, xyx=y^{-1}\rangle.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

von Dyck's Theorem states that if you have a presentation for a group $G$
$$G = \langle X\mid R\rangle$$
(say $X=\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$, and $R=\{r_j(x_i)\}_{j\in J}$)
then, whenever $K$ is any group and $k_i$ is an $I$-tuple of elements of $K$ such that for each $j$, $r_j(k_i)=e_K$, then there exists a (unique) homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to K$ such that $\varphi(x_i)=k_i$ for each $i\in I$.

---

Your presentation for $S_3$ is incorrect. The presentation
$$\langle x,y\mid x^2=e=y^3\rangle$$
defines the free product $C_2*C_3$, which is an infinite group. Instead, you need a relation that connects $x$ and $y$ before you get $S_3$. One example of such a presentation is:
For example, take your group
$$S_3 = \langle x,y\mid x^2=y^3=e, xyx=y^{-1}\rangle.$$

---

So, let's take the preentation I give above,
$$S_3=\langle x,y\mid x^2=e=y^3, xyx=y^{-1}\rangle.$$
von Dyck's Theorem says that if you have any group $K$, and elements $g,h\in K$ such that $g^2=e$, $h^3=e$, and $ghg=h^{-1}$ all hold in $K$, then there is a homomorphism $\varphi\colon S_3\to K$ such that $\varphi(x)=g$ and $\varphi(y)=h$. Now, if you happen to know that $g$ and $h$ generate $K$, then you will also be able to conclude that $\varphi$ is surjective.

For instance, if we take the group $C_4=\{1,z,z^2,z^3\}$ the cyclic group of order $4$, I can take $g=z^2$ and $h=1$; then $g^2 = (z^2)^2 = 1$, $h^3 = (1)^3 = 1$, and $ghg = z^2(1)z^2 = z^4 = 1 = h^{-1}$. So that means that there is a homomorphism $\varphi\colon S_3\to C_3$ with $\varphi(x)=z^2$ and $\varphi(y)=1$; note that this map is not surjective.

---

So, we consider the presentations
$$\begin{align*}
S_3 &= \langle x,y\mid x^2=e=y^3, xyx=y^{-1}\rangle\\
D_3 &= \langle s,r\mid r^3=1, s^2=1, sr=r^{-1}s\rangle.
\end{align*}$$
If we want to use von Dyck's Theorem to prove the groups are isomorphic, we have two options:

1. Use von Dyck's Theorem twice, once to define a map from $S_3$ to $D_3$, and once to define a map from $D_3$ to $S_3$, and then show the maps are inverses of each other; or
2. Use von Dyck's Theorem once to define a map in one direction, and then verify that the map is a bijection (for example, by using that the resulting map is surjective, and/or using knowledge we have about the orders of the groups).

**Option 1.** To define a map from $S_3$ to $D_3$, I need to identify elements of $D_3$ that satisfy the relations satisfied by $x$ and $y$ in $S_3$. I can pick $s$ "for $x$" and $r$ "for $y$". Then $s^2=1$ and $r^3=1$ by assumption; I still need to verify that $srs=r^{-1}$ is true in $D_3$. But indeed, we know that $sr=r^{-1}s$, so
$$srs = (sr)s = (r^{-1}s)s = r^{-1}(ss) = r^{-1}s^2 = r^{-1}.$$
Since $s$ and $r$ satisfy the relations satisfied by $x$ and $y$, von Dyck's theorem guarantees a homomorphism $\varphi\colon S_3\to D_3$ with $\varphi(x)=s$ and $\varphi(y)=r$.

Now, to define a map the other way, we need to find two elements in $S_3$ that satisfy the same relations that $r$ and $s$ do in $D_3$. After some thought, I pick $y$ "for $r$" and $x$ "for $s$". Then I verify that $y$ and $x$ satisfy, in $S_3$, the defining relations that $r$ and $s$ do in $D_3$. Indeed, $y^3=e$, $x^2=e$, and to verify that $xy=y^{-1}x$, we have
$$xy = xy(x^2) = (xyx)x = y^{-1}x.$$
So von Dyck's Theorem guarantees the existence of a homomorphism $\psi\colon D_3\to S_3$ such that $\psi(r)=y$ and $\psi(s)=x$.

Now we have homomorphism $\varphi\colon S_3\to D_3$ and $\psi\colon D_3\to S_3$. We now note that $\psi(\varphi(x)) = \psi(s) = x$, $\psi(\varphi(y))=\psi(r) = y$. So $\psi\circ\varphi=\mathrm{id}_{S_3}$, because they agree on a generating set. And $\varphi(\psi(r)) = \varphi(y) = r$, $\varphi(\psi(s)) = \varphi(x) = s$, so $\varphi\circ\psi=\mathrm{id}_{D_3}$. Thus, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are inverses of each other, and we have that they are isomorphisms.

**Option 2.** As above, we identify elements in one group that satisfy the relations that the generators satisfy in the other group. For example, $s$ "for $x$" and $r$ "for $y$". von Dyck's Theorem now gives us the homomorphism $\varphi\colon S_3\to D_3$ with $\varphi(x)=s$ and $\varphi(y)=r$.

Now, we know that $r$ and $s$ generate $D_3$, so $\varphi$ is surjective. Moreover, we know that both $S_3$ and $D_3$ have six elements each, so we have a surjective morphism from a group of  order six to a group of order six. This means the map is in fact also injective, so $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, proving that $S_3$ is isomorphic to $D_3$.

Note that Option 2 requires you to know more stuff about the groups presented: you need to know their orders already.